# File input not working inside <ion-menu>

Tags: angular, file, ionic-framework, ionic3

while I had not ion-menu in my application,  it worked fine, but after adding this to my code:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let file of fileNames;let i = index;" #item>
      <ion-item [ngClass]="{ 'active':i == isActive}" ion-long-press [interval]="400" (onPressStart)="fileChosen(i)">
        {{file}}
  <button ion-button (click)="deleteFile(i)">Delete file</button>

      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options side="left" (ionSwipe)="save()">

        <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="moreInfo(item)">More Info</button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>

  <input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)">
  <button  (click)="doSome()" [disabled]="isFileChosen">DOSOME</button>
</ion-content>
<ion-nav id="nav" #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

file input stopped open file dialog on device, but opens it in browser. I think that problem is in events because menu opens with swipe, but don't know how to solve that problem. Help me, please

**PACKAGE.JSON**

> {
>       "name": "myApp",
>
> ```
> "version": "0.0.1",
> "author": "Ionic Framework",
> "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
> "private": true,
> "scripts": {
>     "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
>     "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
>     "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
>     "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
>     "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
> },
> "dependencies": {
>     "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
>     "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
>     "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
>     "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
>     "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
>     "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
>     "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
>     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
>     "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
>     "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
>     "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
>     "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
>     "b-spline": "^2.0.1",
>     "canvasjs": "^1.8.1",
>     "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
>     "chartjs": "^0.3.24",
>     "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
>     "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.1.0",
>     "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
>     "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3",
>     "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
>     "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
>     "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
>     "ionic-angular": "3.6.0",
>     "ionic-long-press": "^1.2.0",
>     "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
>     "ionicons": "3.0.0",
>     "rxjs": "5.4.0",
>     "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
>     "zone.js": "0.8.12"
> },
> "devDependencies": {
>     "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.3",
>     "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2",
>     "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1",
>     "ionic": "3.7.0",
>     "typescript": "2.3.4"
> },
> "description": "An Ionic project",
> "cordova": {
>     "plugins": {
>         "cordova-plugin-device": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
>         "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-file": {}
>     },
>     "platforms": [
>         "android"
>     ]
> } }
> ```

Comment: Can you show whole code on your menu then?

Comment: @Sampath, I updated code in the topic

Comment: @Sampath, also, swipe on list-items not working too

Comment: Can you show the `package.json` file too?

Comment: @Sampath, added it too

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `swipe` as shown below.There is no `(ionSwipe)` now.

```
 <ion-item-options side="left" (swipe)="save($event)">
```

See this too: [**swipe**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-preview-app/blob/master/src/pages/gestures/basic/template.html#L28)

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you? `input`?

Comment: <input type="file">

Comment: No. Problem is that in my browser, when I click on input button - shows file dialog. But when I build apk and upload it to my android device @6.0.1 and click on input button - nothing happens

Comment: Yes, until I added <ion-menu> to project

Comment: It seems your `*ngFor` loop is having a serious issue.You have accsess the loop's object after closing the loop too here : `<button ion-button (click)="deleteFile(i)">Delete file</button>`. What is  `i` here?

Comment: i - counter, number of element in array with file names

Comment: You cannot access that after closing the `for` loop.It is being ended it here `</ion-item-sliding>`.But your `delete` button is in way bottom of that.Why?

Comment: yeah, that was my mistake, sorry. Did not notice it

Comment: but this is not the main theme

Comment: If you're not sharing the relevant code then how we can help you? No one can see your dev machine's screen no?

Comment: that code works, there is no errors in console. Just little mistake and this is not influence to main topic problem. Problem is that file input does not open file dialog

Comment: Did you debug on the device console?

Comment: Use this `ionic cordova run android --prod --device`

Comment: See this too: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/